# Is there a way to track how a file gets served from the IIS handler pipeline?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to figure out if static assets are being routed into the asp.net pipieline/Sitecore CMS at all, but it's hard to tell without some way of being able to track what modules/handlers went into handling an HTTP request from IIS. Is there any way/tool to tap into IIS that will give me information on how a particular request was handled, which assemblies it went through, etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove permissions to the file, you should get an error page that displays the name of the HTTP handler if you're browsing from the same machine as IIS.

Comment: Hi, what if the file doesn't exist? I'm facing similar issue in MVC application context. Thank you

Comment: You can handle an Application event in Global.asax and break the debugger to check the HttpContext object for the handler.